# messenger-ruby ArgumentError (missing keyword: payload)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

After upgrading to version 1.2.0 of the messenger-ruby gem, which I am using to get the Facebook Messenger user's location in a Quick Reply, it appears that messenger-ruby cannot parse the returned location attachment object. This error occurs before I get a chance to send back a 200 OK response so the controller gets hung up.  How do I resolve this?

Here is the snippet from the heroku log file:

```
2017-01-23T03:15:52.544541+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/messenger/webhook" for 173.252.123.140 at 2017-01-23 03:15:52 +0000
2017-01-23T03:15:52.547400+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by MessengerController#webhook as */*
2017-01-23T03:15:52.547618+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"object"=>"page", "entry"=>[{"id"=>"776445229159135", "time"=>1485141352448, "messaging"=>[{"sender"=>{"id"=>"938332056296353"}, "recipient"=>{"id"=>"776445229159135"}, "timestamp"=>1485120971441, "message"=>{"mid"=>"mid.1485120971441:34f1a70557", "seq"=>3197, "attachments"=>[{"title"=>"James's Location", "url"=>"url redacted", "type"=>"location", "payload"=>{"coordinates"=>{"lat"=>36.074067028043, "long"=>-95.645990201969}}}]}}]}], "messenger"=>{"object"=>"page", "entry"=>[{"id"=>"776445229159135", "time"=>1485141352448, "messaging"=>[{"sender"=>{"id"=>"938332056296353"}, "recipient"=>{"id"=>"776445229159135"}, "timestamp"=>1485120971441, "message"=>{"mid"=>"mid.1485120971441:34f1a70557", "seq"=>3197, "attachments"=>[{"title"=>"James's Location", "url"=>"url redacted, "type"=>"location", "payload"=>{"coordinates"=>{"lat"=>36.074067028043, "long"=>-95.645990201969}}}]}}]}]}}
2017-01-23T03:15:52.549321+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2017-01-23T03:15:52.549885+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-01-23T03:15:52.549888+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/messenger_controller.rb:8:in `webhook'
2017-01-23T03:15:52.549887+00:00 app[web.1]: ArgumentError (missing keyword: payload)
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:  I'm not sure what happened, but I did some more debugging and this started working.  I copied the object that Facebook was sending me and opened up a console after cloning the gem from github and there was no problem at all!